# SED to delete C Program comments

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to delete the comment line in a C program with sed in linux, assuming that each comment line contains the start and end tokens without any other statements before and after.

For example, the code below:

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
[TAB][SPACE] /* another empty comment line here */
/* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
```

becomes

```
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
/* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
```

I know that this regex

```
^\s?\/\*.*\*\/$
```

matches the lines that I need to delete. However, the following command:

```
sed -i -e  's/^\s?\/\*.*\*\/$//g' filename
```

does not do the trick.

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should include `/* first comment */ non comment /* second comment */` in your sample as that'd be the hard for a sed script to handle correctly. None of your existing answers would handle it correctly, they'd all think it was a comment line.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297346/how-can-i-delete-all-characters-falling-under-including

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
$ sed -e  '/^\s*\/\*.*\*\/$/d' file
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
/* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
```

Notes:

1. `^\s?` matches zero or one spaces.  It looks like you want to match zero or one or more spaces.  So, we use instead `^\s*`.
2. Since you want to delete the lines rather than replace them with empty lines, the command to use is `d` for delete.
3. It is not necessary to delimit a regex with `/`.  We can use `|`, for example:

   ```
   sed -e  '\|^\s*/\*.*\*/$|d' file
   ```

   This eliminates the need to escape the `/`.  Depending on how many times `/` appears in a regex, this may or may not be simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '{o=$0; gsub(/\*\//,"\n"); gsub(/\/\*[^\n]*\n/,"")} NF{print o}' file
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
/* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
/* first comment */ non comment /* second comment */
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
/* a comment line in a C program */
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
     /* another empty comment line here */
/* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
/* first comment */ non comment /* second comment */
```

and uses awk because once you're past a simple s/old/new/ everythings easier (and more efficient, more portable, etc.) with awk. The above will delete any empty lines - if that's a problem then update your sample input/output to include that but it's a easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is replacing your regex with a empty string

```
sed -i -e  's/^\s?\/\*.*\*\/$//g' filename
```

that means

```
sed -i -'s/pattern_to_find/replacement/g' : g means the whole file.
```

What you need to do is delete the line with the regex

```
sed -i -e  '/^\s?\/\*.*\*\/$/d' filename
```